# Swift: Use of unresolved identifier 'present'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIView` added to `UIViewController`, and some code of them

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let listView = ListView()
    self.view.addSubview(listView)
 }
```

ListView.swift

```
 class ListView: UIView {
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(btnGO)
   }

   convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
   }

   lazy var btnGO:(UIButton) = {
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 34))
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    //some codes
    return btn
  }()

  @objc func btnClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let shareWOW = "some content"
    let objectsToShare = [shareWOW]
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: objectsToShare,
        applicationActivities: nil)
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.frame
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self
    activityController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
 }
```

I always get error information `Use of unresolved identifier 'present'`, and I know `UIActivityViewController` should be placed in UIViewController, and my question is I place the function `btnClicked` in ViewController.swift, how to call this function in a UIView as `ListView.swift`? Many thanks

Comment: `UIViewControllers` present other `UIViewControllers`. `UIViews` cannot present another view controller, they can only have `UIViews` as a subview - and auto layout *may* be able to show them dynamically. This is actually the basics of both lifecycles. If you wish to present a `UIActivityViewController` - which is simply a subclassed `UIViewController`, you need to do it from a `UIViewController1, not a `UIView` - even it's root view.

Answer (score 0):

[present(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) method should be used with `UIViewController` instance. You can't call this method in a `UIView` subclass. Use delegate to call a method in `ViewController` from `ListView` and present `UIActivityViewController` from the `ViewController` like this

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ListViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let listView = ListView()
        listView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(listView)
    }
    func btnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        let shareWOW = "some content"
        let objectsToShare = [shareWOW]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: objectsToShare,
            applicationActivities: nil)
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

ListView.swift

```
protocol ListViewDelegate {
    func btnClicked(sender:UIButton)
}

class ListView: UIView {

    var delegate: ListViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(btnGO)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    lazy var btnGO:(UIButton) = {
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 34))
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        //some codes
        return btn
    }()

    @objc func btnClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        delegate?.btnClicked(sender: sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to add parent controller in which you want to add a another view

Comment: @AnilKumar you can't get parent controller from a subview. And passing the parent view controller reference to is subview isn't good

Comment: No in your viewcontroller class where you write present just add over the parent class

Comment: @AnilKumar Do you mean to add self. before present?

Comment: Yes self or you can use your navigationcontroller

Comment: @AnilKumar self. isn't necessary. Both are same